# Closing down socket connections after comms

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

I am trying to implement a fairly simple TCP/IP socket proxy which listens on one port and then passes the messages on to another server on a different port. At the same time it should also pass response messages from the upstream server back to the downstream client again.

Everything seems to work as expected, except for the graceful shutting down of the `net.Conn` connections once a client disconnects. Below is the implementation I have currently. Some comments about the code follow underneath.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "bufio"
)

const localAddr = "127.0.0.1:8001"
const remoteAddr = "127.0.0.1:8002"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting")
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8001")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for {
        fmt.Println("Awaiting connection")
        src, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        fmt.Printf("Connection accepted from %s\r\n", src.LocalAddr().String())

        dialer := &net.Dialer{}
        dst, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", remoteAddr)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error dialing %s\r\n", remoteAddr)
            continue
        }

        go forwarder("outgoing", src, dst)
        go forwarder("incoming", dst, src)
    }
}

func forwarder(id string, src, dst net.Conn) {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(src)
    for input.Scan() {
        b := input.Bytes()
        _, err := dst.Write(b)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Forwarding error: %v\r\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(input.Text())
        }
    }

    if err := input.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Source connection (%s) closed unexpectedly: %v", id, err)
    }

    if err := src.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error closing source connection (%s): %v\r\n", id, err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Source connection (%s) closed gracefully\r\n", id)
    }

    if err := dst.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error closing destination connection (%s): %v\r\n", id, err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Destination connection (%s) closed gracefully\r\n", id)
    }
}
```

So at the end of the `main()` function there is an infinite loop which accepts new client connections, create a new dialer connection for each and then starts two goroutines to pass traffic from one to the other and vice versa.

The `forwarder()` function is where the passing around of messages happen. The `for input.Scan()` loop blocks until the client closes the connection or an error occurs on the connection - at least that's how I understand it and how it works when I connect from a terminal using `nc 127.0.0.1 8001`. Anything I type on the terminal then is delivered to the proxy listener and forwarded upstream. On the upstream side I have a simple echo server just for testing and so the message is sent all the way back to the terminal again. Cool bananas!

When I close the connection from the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. The goroutine which passes messages from the listener to the dialer exits the `for input.Scan()` loop without an error, as expected, and closes the listener and dialer connections. So far so good. But the problem is that the second goroutine which passes messages from the dialer to the listener now exits the `for input.Scan()` loop because of an error (use of closed network connection) and then still tries to close the two connections which obviously fail. Should I simply ignore these errors and carry on with my life or is there a more elegant way of closing down both connections?

Comment: The close code in the question is OK for some application scenarios.  There are scenarios where the application should call CloseWrite before calling Close.   The code in the question discards end of line markers.  Consider using io.Copy to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón, the EOL markers were indeed an issue that I struggled with as well but didn't want to add to this question. The reason I'm not using io.Copy is because I then don't get a copy of the buffer which I can log as in the 8th line of the forwarder() function. Is there a better way to do that?